# Upgrading Tier (Sku) via Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer not working

Tags: powershell, azure, runbook, azure-analysis-services

I want to upscale and downscale my Azure Analysis Services with PowerShell (Automation Runbook), but changing the Tier (Sku) doesn't seem to work. However there are no errors. Any suggestions?

```
# PowerShell code
# Connect to a connection to get TenantId and SubscriptionId
$Connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name "AzureRunAsConnection"
$TenantId = $Connection.TenantId
$SubscriptionId = $Connection.SubscriptionId

# Get the service principal credentials connected to the automation account. 
$null = $SPCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "SSISJoost"

# Login to Azure ($null is to prevent output, since Out-Null doesn't work in Azure)
Write-Output "Login to Azure using automation account 'SSISJoost'."
$null = Login-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $TenantId -SubscriptionId $SubscriptionId -Credential $SPCredential

# Select the correct subscription
Write-Output "Selecting subscription '$($SubscriptionId)'."
$null = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionID $SubscriptionId

# Get variable values
$ResourceGroupName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'ResourceGroupName'
$AnalysisServerName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name 'AnalysisServerName'


# Get old status (for testing/logging purpose only)
$OldAsSetting = Get-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AnalysisServerName

try
{
    # changing tier
    Write-Output "Upgrade $($AnalysisServerName) to S1. Current tier: $($OldAsSetting.Sku.Name)" 
    Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AnalysisServerName -Sku "S1"
}
catch
{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
}

Write-Output "Done"

# Get new status (for testing/logging purpose only)
$NewAsSetting = Get-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $AnalysisServerName
Write-Output "New tier: $($NewAsSetting.Sku.Name)"
```

[image]

using [Set-AzureRmAnalysisServicesServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.analysisservices/set-azurermanalysisservicesserver?view=azurermps-3.8.0)

Comment: Apparently it's a bug in the AAS module. Have to wait for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

There was a little bug in the PowerShell **AzureRM.AnalysisServices** module. It has been fixed in [0.4.0 (Thursday, June 08 2017)](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.AnalysisServices/0.4.0)

Now the code finally works: http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2017/06/schedule-upscaledownscale-azure.html
[image]